# Changing title of node when saving

Tags: 6, forms, nodes

Whenever an user saves a node I want to prefix it with table autoincrement-id so that the id is unique.

So if the title of node is "xyz" then it should be saved as unique id "299999-xyz". Ideally this id should be the node-id which is unique but it may not be possible to know the actual id until the node is saved in the table.

**What is the best way to accomplish it?**

I'm thinking of changing the title in the form validate function. This id can be numeric time() value.

**PS:**I'll have tons of such nodes so when linking them from other nodes (node-reference) this id will uniquely identify such nodes in "autocomplete textbox" in node forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you can do this via a [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) when `$op == "presave"`.

```
function mymodule_nodeapi (&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL)
{
    if ($op == "presave") {
      $unique = mymodule_get_unique_number();
      $title = preg_replace("/^\d+\-/", "", $node->title);
      $node->title = $unique . "-" . $title;
    }
}
```

The trick is to tweak the PCRE pattern to extract the unique number from the $title.  Putting in better delimiyters would help.  You could always save off the original title in a CCK field that only uid==1 can edit, and build the node title from that.

EDIT:  Just re-read the question.  This will change the title every time you save.  Not sure if you want that or not.  You can edit the logic to only do this once, based on the preg results.

Comment: I do not see hook_nodeapi on the api.Drupal listings

Comment: The function is linked in my answer.  It is a D4.7-6 hook.  D7 split out the ops into individual hooks via the node API.  Question is tagged for Drupal 6.

Comment: During presave will $node->nid be available?

Comment: No, hence using a made-up function called mymodule_get_unique_number().

Answer (score 7):

Use the module "[Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle)". This allows you to use tokens on the title field. Once enabled you can set any pattern for the title. Set your pattern on /admin/content/node-type/YOURCONTENTTYPE to "[nid] - [title]" for example. Already existing nodes can be updated automatically.

Comment: In case of newly saved nodes what'd nid be replaced with?

Comment: The nid of the node when its saved.

Comment: But I'm not able to set title. This module gives only two options so if I enter a title then it'd do nothing. So it'll work only if a node is reedited and not created a new. If I use another cck field as title2 then it can work but then the default title field would be wasted.

Comment: Also looks like I can't use [nid] for new nodes it seems to be empty

Comment: You're right, the [nid] is only set on update. Sorry about that. Check this thread: http://drupal.org/node/194197

Answer (score 0):

This should also be possible using php by invoking [hook_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--node.php/function/hook_insert/6). This hook is called after the node is saved and the nid is available, so you can then make changes and resave the node.

Comment: Does this work with all content types, or just when the module instantiating the hook also creates a type via hook_node_info() ?

Comment: It works with any content type!  It's a really neat hook :p

Comment: Curious.  The note on the API doc page says "To take action when nodes of any type are inserted (not just nodes of the type(s) defined by this module), use hook_nodeapi() instead."

Comment: Bah..my bad..hook_insert is the standard for D7.  For D6 you still should use hook_nodeapi with the $op as insert :p

Comment: This second level updation I don't want to do. Say during server crash or site errors the node will not be in correct state then